# Elasticsearch sum by sum from max

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, elastic-beats

I need some help with finding total number of messages from all the topics.

The document below has +million number of topics,partition and offsets.

I need to get total number of offsets :

```
"kafka": {
  "partition": {
    "topic": {
      "name": "testTopic20181206"
    },
    "broker": {
      "id": 4,
      "address": "localhost:9092"
    },
    "partition": {
      "insync_replica": true,
      "id": 0,
      "leader": 3,
      "replica": 1
    },
    "offset": {
      "newest": 17330676,
      "oldest": 0
   }
  }
```

Query that i am using is :

```
  GET metricbeat-6*/_search
  {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "Topic": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "kafka.partition.topic.name",
          "size": 10000
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "Partition": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "kafka.partition.partition.id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
            "Partition": {
              "max": {
                "field": "kafka.partition.offset.newest"
              }
            }
            }

          }
        }
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: The max offset won't tell you the number of messages currently in a Kafka topic, only the total that have been sent since the creation of the topic

Comment: being said that, i need to get total number of offsets for now...

Comment: And what is this currently returning? Are you sure that you want to pass in `"size": 0,`? And youre taking the max, but sounds like you want the `sum` of the latest offsets over all partitions

Comment: And if you could post a [mcve] of your metricbeat config and ES mapping, that would be appreciated.